# Are there any open-source calculator keypads for iOS development?

Tags: ios, user-interface, custom-controls

Does anyone know if there is an already made Objective-c calculator keypad available for use? I'm looking for something that works in conjunction with a native text field. Instead of a native keyboard, it displays a calculator keypad, that lets you perform calculations straight into the native field. This is similar to keypads on some converter apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard keyboard and add a toolbar as the accessory view of your textfield and add some calculator functions of your choice.